# Subtle diff when running in intellij and executing jar

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, gradle, kotlin

I'm running out of ideas...

My spring boot app behaves fine when I run it in indellij and **gradle idea plugin is applied** (*apply plugin: 'idea'*).
Once I remove the plugin from *build.gradle* it behaves similarly to app executed with *java -jar app.jar* - there is subtle but important difference, description below.

I have the following scenario, current tx fails due to some exception, tx is marked as roll-back-only, exception is caught and its handling consists of registering post tx recovery activity with *TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization* (new tx).

The code works fine in intellij with idea plugin, when I remove plugin declaration or run spring boot jar with *java -jar* registering process (post tx failure task) fails with exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction synchronization is not active
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(TransactionSynchronizationManager.java:291) ~[spring-tx-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
```

Btw, the code is in kotlin if it matters.
Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I think there is some kind of race condition because in debug mode, even w/o idea plugin, the app behaves as expected (registering process is successful).

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem and the root cause was quite surprising...

Apparently there's a problem with correct processing of custom Spring annotation.
The method which was supposed to open a new transaction was not annotated with a standard @Transactional annotation, but with custom, application specific annotation (@Transactional with custom tx settings). Debugging session revealed that new tx was not being open. That's it! Inlining custom annotation nearly solved a problem.
Another flaw I detected was a function which was not *open*, quite strange because the function was not transaction entry point (som further call).

Kotlin compiler bug?
Anyway, lessons learned - pay attention to custom annotations behaviour; refresh knowledge about rules for final/open.